# Casting const references to and from void pointers

Tags: c++11

**Problem:** I have a class of parameters which I'm passing around as `const Some_Class& param` because these parameters aren't changing. I need to pass these parameters to external library ([GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/)) which is accepting `void* param`. I can't cast from `const&` to `void*`, except with using `const_cast`. I heared that `const_cast` is not generally right solution, is this the correct use case for it?

**My solution:** As a solution I'm now using wrapper structure

```
struct wrapper{const Some_class& param;};

void gsl_func(void* param){
    const Some_class& my_param = static_cast<wrapper*>(param)->param;
}

void my_func(const Some_class& my_param){
    wrapper my_wrapper = {my_param};
    gsl_func(&my_wrapper);
}
```

Which doesn't seems like the most elegant solution as I have to do this before every call to GSL. Is there some standardize way how to do this better?

Comment: Your workaround is not only inelegant, it opens the door to undefined behavior, if the wrapper's lifetime is shorter than the object it references.  Is the opaque pointer only used for callbacks during execution of the directly-called GSL function, or is it stored for later?

Comment: In this particular scenario, careful use of `const_cast` (that is, you must add `const` back immediately when converting back from `void*`) is safe.

Comment: @BenVoigt it is used only for GSL